# Choosing optimal sample points for cubic spline approximation of sinusoid with polynomial argument

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, approximation, sampling, spline

My problem consists as follows. Say I have a sinusoidal function whose argument is a cubic polynomial:
$$f(t) = \sin(at^3+bt^2+ct+d) \quad a, b, c, d\in \mathbb{R}, \quad t\in[T_1, T_2]$$

I want to approximate this with cubic spline $F(t)$ with boundary conditions $F'(T_1)=f'(T_1)$ and $F'(T_2)=f'(T_2)$. Construction of spline form sample points I am familiar with, **my problem in this case is choosing the sample point set**. Namely, I want that

- The number of sample points is as little as possible
- We ensure the bound on deviation, i.e. $$|F(t)-f(t)|<d, \quad d\in \mathbb{R}$$
  for all $t\in[T_1, T_2]$

I am going to use a computer for this procedure, so I guess the solution should be some kind of algorithm. Few things I was thinking about:

- Cubic spline is bounded by maximum of 4th derivative of the original function. However, although I can compute the 4th derivative, I do not know how to calculate the maximum of it.
- Divide and conquer based algorithm. I start with three sample points, perform cubic spline, check for the max error in each of the segments, if its bigger than $d$ split in, perform the procedure again. The problem is the max error evaluation. If we say that $Q, R$ are cubic polynomials, $Q$ argument of the sinusoidal in $f$ and $R$ the approximating segment of the spline, the error is
  $$ \sin(Q(t)) - R(t)$$
  and to find t when the error attains maximum, we need to solve
  $$ Q'(t)\cdot \cos(Q(t))-R'(t)=0$$
  which I do not know how to do. Approach it maybe with the fact that $\sin(Q(t)))=R(t)$ at the boundaries?

Any help or advice how I should proceed with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’d recommend your second idea (divide and conquer). You don’t need to estimate the error exactly. Just measure it at some sample points (say 10 or 20 points per segment) and use this as an estimate of the maximum.